# Symfony and data handling

Tags: php, symfony

Lately I have gotten myself into PHP framework Symfony and I got to understand some fundementals, however I am having trouble with finding a good example concerning data retrieval (from a database) in Symfony.

Since Symfony is an object oriented way of programming, I thought it would be best to retreive data, save certain fields as properties of a certain object (name would be related to the name of the table) and return it to a twig template.

My template would look something like this:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>Page: {{ page.title }}</h1>
    {% for x in Object_Name %}
        { x.age}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

How should I define a class or object and its properties and how should a controller look like to pass such object to the template given in the example above? I have been looking around on the web but it seems like there is not much content concerning data handling and Symfony PHP.

Can anyone refer me to a page I can look for this kind of information?

Because I have been used to working with MVC in ASP.NET, I know these things would happen in a folder called `models` which would contain classes and its properties, but this does not seem the case with Symfony.

Comment: Try to look in to Doctrine and entities [link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `Entities` in Symfony2.

Those are classes, that represent tables in your database.

You can create them from existing database tables or create new one over generated entities.

Have a closer look into the documentation http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html

Comment: Thank you, I think this is what I have been looking for, but was not sure what the term was that Symfony uses.

Comment: They're are like the Models you already know, but with a different naming. Personally, I use the term `Model` only for classes, that are coming from a database or any other source of information, that isn't handled by doctrine.